# Multiple Views in Android from OpenCV images

Tags: java, c++, image, opencv, gridview

I have just written a complete application using OpenCV. Till now its fine when I want to view images from OpenCV. Basically I do some processing in JNI/C++ via opencv and throw back the image to Java. The image is then shown in a org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView

I want to see multiple views of the steps that I perform on an image. E.g. Smooth, sharpen, flip and then finally rotate. I want these steps being show to the user simultaneously.

Is there a well known way of show multiple JavaCameraViews? More like a grid view with each entry showing a particular step? My main issue is that how I can send the images from each step back to Java. I cant keep going smoothen the image go back to java, show the image and then come back to jni do the sharpen step. This is where I am stuck.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: check if this helps - if you want only image filters http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-image-filters.html

Comment: Am doing all the processing in JNI/C++ so I need to send the processed images back to java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe, something like a picture whithin a picture ?

e.g, if im is a 90x90 grayscale image, and mRgba is what you blit into the JavaCameraView:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(im, im, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA); // it needs the same format for composition
im.copyTo(mRgba.submat(0,90,0,90));                // y,y+h, x,x+w
```

Comment: but I will have to wait for the steps. This will be like waiting a bit too long, though it is not a bad idea. Really liked it. But i am looking for something better.